# calling website home page with access token

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-web-app-service, access-token

I want to call website home page from postman.I have one AD application(Ad1) for which I can get accesstoken. Website AD application has given access to this AD applicaiton(Ad).

I can get access token for AD1 application. Now when I try to make get request to home page with that access token, it is sending response with page which says signin to azure active directory.

Why signin is required in this case , since I already have access token?

When I see via fiddler , once I login to website subsequent calls to that website don't pass token but instead pass cookie.I can see that webpage via fiddler also if I pass that same cookie.

For my case is it possible to access webpage with access token?

Answer (score 0):

Your website uses cookie + OpenID Connect authentication probably. It will not accept a Bearer token unless you configure it so.

It is possible if you configure JWT Bearer token authentication to be used as well.

Comment: I tried to configure JWT Bearer token  by adding to my startup.cs app.UseCookieAuthentication
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication, Not in this case which one will be triggered if request comes from postman?

Comment: I tried this and still request goes to app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication